# How do i show the existence of two secquences that converges to a border point?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

My task is this:

Show that if $\textbf{c}$ is a border point for $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, then there exists two sequences $\{\textbf{x}_n\}$ and $\{\textbf{y}_n\}$ that converges to $\textbf{c}$ such that one sequence contain only points that are in $A$, while the other sequence contain points that are not in $A$.

My work:

Since $\textbf{c}$ is a border point, one can always construct a ball around it, call it $B(\textbf{c}, r)$ which contains both interior and exterior points of $A$ since that's the definition of a border point. Now one could assume that we have two sequences $\{\textbf{x}_n\}\in A$ and $\{\textbf{y}_n\}\notin A$ that converges to $\textbf{c}$ and do the $\epsilon /\delta$ proof ?(i thought), but my teacher told me this was wrong since we needed to construct the sequences. I was told that sometimes one just have to "cough" something up. So i need some help in doing that and some explanation on the procedure of proving this. Note that this is an assignement for multivariable calculus and that i'm very new to proving things in general so don't be to harsh on me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $r_1=1$ then you have two points $x_1\in A$ and $ y1$ not in $A$. Chose $r_2< \min (d(x_1,c), d(y_1,c)$ and consider the new ball $C(c,r_2)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that either $c\in A$ or $c \in A^c$. Without loss of generality, suppose $c \in A^c$. (Otherwise, interchange $A$ and $A^c$.) Then we can take $y_n = c$ for all $n$.

To construct the other sequence, observe that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, the ball $B(c, 1/n)$ contains some element of $A$. Choose $x_n$ to be any element of $B(c, 1/n)$. (Careful, we need the axiom of (countable) choice here!) Doing this for each $n$ gives us a sequence satisfying $|x_n - c| \leq 1/n$ for every $n$, and therefore $|x_n - c| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Equivalently, $x_n \to c$.

Comment: Could you explain why we want the sequence $y_n = c$ for all $n$? And have you showed that $y_n$ converges to $c$ with your first statement?

Comment: @Thomas Is it not clear that if $y_n = c$ for all $n$, then the sequence converges to $c$?

Comment: That is perfectly clear, i got it now, just had to let it sink in, thanks alot for making it clear and consice!

Answer (score 1):

Consider balls of the form of $B(c,\frac{1}{n}).$

These balls are shrinking and hence you can pick points from these shrinking balls to construct your sequence that will get close to $c$.